# How to select which class to display in class hierarchy in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, class-hierarchy

I have turned on class hierarchy view for Java in eclipse and it is showing some arbitrary class, unrelated with my editor or something other apparently.

`Link with editor` option is on and has no effect.

How to fix?

**UPDATE**

`Link with editor` is in `Hierarchy view`:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. click on the classname
2. press F4 to see the hierarchy

Comment: Is it possible to make it automatically show current class in the editor? Otherwise what does "Link with editor" mean?

Comment: I don't know about any way to make the "Type Hierarchy" view refresh on clicks to classnames. You probably saw "Link with editor" in the "Package Explorer" view, there it means that the file you are editing is selected in the Package Explorer view (it makes navigation easier in big projects).

Comment: No, `Link...` is from Hierarchy view.

Comment: I've never seen this menu, good to know there is one. About your question: seems like its a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Here is Erich Gamma's response from 2002: "The back linking works only when the type is visible in the hierarchy.
For performance reasons (type hierarchy computation is expensive) we don't want to recompute a type hierarchy on editor switching."

It seems they have never addressed this counter-intuitive behavior.

See the following bugs for details:

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=8748
- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=41525

Answer (score 0):

Yes Link with Editor is not working, I think its a bug. Alternatively,

If editor is opened then keep caret on the class name then press <kbd>F4</kbd> or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>. This opens a dialog. Enter the class name for which you want to see its type hierarchy.

Dragging a file from `Package Explorer` to `Type Hierarchy` view also works.